# Gridview delete row from database

Tags: c#, sql, gridview

I want to to delete record(s) from table through C# gridview. The problem is that the rows are only getting deleted from gridview and not from table. I want to remove them from DB as well. here is my code.

```
private void Delete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (this.dataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count > 0)
    {
        string  a = (string )this.dataGridView1.CurrentCell.Value;
            dataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(this.dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Index);
        DeleteRecord(a);
    }
```

Now I want the definition of function `DeleteRecord(a)` its a humble request to give the code for this function which will obviously have the sql query so that i may delete the rows  from table by getting the id of selected row.

Comment: That is impossible without knowing your table definition & how you're passing table PK or some other significant identifier to the datagrid.

Comment: __Do not__ call a `DataGridView`a `GridView`!! This is wrong and confusing and got you one wrong answer already. Always call things by their __right__ name! Yes, it takes __four__ letters more to type, but when asking for help here is __not__ the time to be so lazy..! - Also: __Always__ tag your question correctly. Here you ought to add the Winforms tag!!!

Answer (score 1):

It is rather impossible to tell the exact answer.
Multiple ways:Let me show one.

1)Aspx page

```
<asp:GridView DataKeyNames="CategoryID" ID="GridView1" 
       runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
       OnRowCommand="GridView1_RowCommand" 
       OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound" 
       OnRowDeleted="GridView1_RowDeleted" OnRowDeleting="GridView1_RowDeleting">
  <Columns>
   <asp:BoundField DataField="CategoryID" HeaderText="CategoryID" />
   <asp:BoundField DataField="CategoryName" HeaderText="CategoryName" />
   <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Select">
     <ItemTemplate>
       <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" 
         CommandArgument='<%# Eval("CategoryID") %>' 
         CommandName="Delete" runat="server">
         Delete</asp:LinkButton>
     </ItemTemplate>
   </asp:TemplateField>
  </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

2)Add rowdatabound event.

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, 
                         GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
  {
    LinkButton l = (LinkButton)e.Row.FindControl("LinkButton1"); 
    l.Attributes.Add("onclick", "javascript:return " +
    "confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this record " +
    DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "CategoryID") + "')"); 
  }
}
```

3)And finally RowCommand:

```
protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, 
                         GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.CommandName == "Delete")
  {
    // get the categoryID of the clicked row
    int categoryID = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
    // Delete the record 
    DeleteRecordByID(categoryID);
    // Implement this on your own :) 
  }
}
```